# Will my dev iphone "expire" for development purposes the way my old mac did?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

I had an older mac that all of a sudden became "too old" to submit my apps to the apple app store.  Now I need to buy a used iPhone for development/testing and would like to save money and buy the cheapest oldest one that I can, but am worried that XCode will say "this iPhone is too old", forcing me to get a newer one.  Does anyone know if that's the case?

Answer (score 2):

All hardware becomes obsolete eventually. As of today, Apple requires that iOS apps support iOS 4.3 or later. So you need an iPhone or iPad than can run at least iOS 4.3.

Of course that is likely to change later this year when iOS 8 comes out. Apple may change the minimum to be iOS 5 or even iOS 6.

If you want your dev iPhone to work for at least a couple of years, get one that can run iOS 7. This mean iPhone 4 or newer. But it is should be noted that the iPhone 4 will (most likely) never support iOS 8 or higher. It barely runs iOS 7.

So your goal should be to get the newest phone you can, not the oldest. Otherwise you'll be looking to buy another one next year.

As an Apple developer you need to get used to keeping current. That is Apple's way.